# Systrace for Windows

Tags: windows, strace

I'm looking for a Windows equivalent of [Systrace](http://www.citi.umich.edu/u/provos/systrace/) or at least [strace](http://linux.die.net/man/1/strace). I'm aware of 
[StraceNT](http://www.intellectualheaven.com/default.asp?BH=projects&H=strace.htm), but wondering if there are any more alternatives out there. Specifically, I'm looking for a specific way to programmatically enforce system call policies, though this can be after the fact rather than actively stopping them.

Is there a good way to do this currently?

Comment: Also related - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/864839/monitoring-certain-system-calls-done-by-a-process-in-windows

Answer (score 32, accepted):

WinDbg's Logger.exe is the closest to strace: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/logger-and-logviewer

EDIT: There's also windbg's wt: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/wt--trace-and-watch-data-

Comment: However, it's more like ltrace than strace because it captures library calls rather than syscalls.

Comment: @BrunoMartinez : you don’t need to specify a memory address for using strace.

Comment: The only problem I met was windbg stopped at a certain software breakpoint, not at the startup where I was expected.So there were several syscalls I failed to capture.

Answer (score 44):

A few options:

[Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx)

Also, see this article about tools built into Windows 7:

[Core OS Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee412263.aspx)

Comment: I just used ProcessMonitor to find out why a process was hanging - turns out it was trying to access a file which it couldn't delete... would never have figured it out without ProcMon

Comment: I use strace quite a bit on Linux and came across this question while looking for similar tool on Windows for troubleshooting the issue I was having with NANT.  I tried Process Monitor, set filter to include only Nant.exe and excluding everything else, also set filter for register access only where I was having problem, and quickly figure out the issue I was having.  I highly recommend Process Monitor.

Comment: @djhaskin987 : In my case I have a program which load some files ; buffer them to ʀᴀᴍ *(so there’s no handle left)* and crash. As there’s no handle left process monitor is no help.

Comment: @hshib : the problem with process monitor is a process don’t need an handle to access a file. So in a case like mine *(trying to see which config file cause a crash)*, it’s no help.

Answer (score 18):

The Dr. Memory (http://drmemory.org) tool comes with a system call tracing tool called drstrace that lists all system calls made by a target application along with their arguments: http://drmemory.org/strace_for_windows.html

For programmatically enforcing system call policies, you could use the same underlying engines as drstrace: the DynamoRIO tool platform (http://dynamorio.org) and the DrSyscall system call monitoring library (http://drmemory.org/docs/page_drsyscall.html).  These use dynamic binary translation technology, which does incur some overhead (20%-30% in steady state, but much higher when running new code such as launching a big desktop app), which may or may not be suitable for your purposes.

Answer (score 15):

[API Monitor](http://www.rohitab.com/apimonitor) looks very useful for this purpose.

Comment: This is an excellent program, shows detailed function params/return values, allows you to breakpoint when certain conditions are met, many different hooking method so it can be used on a lot of processes that don't like to be inspected.

Answer (score 8):

Here is a pretty intersting article, I don't know if it hits the target you are looking for but I think you may find it leading you in the direction you want.

http://jbremer.org/intercepting-system-calls-on-x86_64-windows/

Comment: Thanks, that's pretty good. I guess it means we're still a long way off a nice and functional strace on Windows...

Answer (score 2):

There are several tools all built around Xperf.  It's rather complex but very powerful -- see the [quick start guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff190983%28VS.85%29.aspx).  There are other useful resources on the [Windows Performance Analysis](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/performance/default.aspx) page

Comment: strace is unrelated to performance. It simply prints which system calls a process makes. The performance tools don't seem to do that.

Comment: First URL now redirects to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/xperf/quick-start---enabling-data-capture-on-process-launch?redirectedfrom=MSDN. Second URL redirects to a [generic MS page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/) and seems to be lost.

Answer (score 2):

You can use process monitor written by Mark Russinovich.  This is a fantastic little application that will allow you to attach to any running process on the system and see all of the system calls that process is currently making.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx

Comment: djhaskin987 already mentioned Process Monitor in his earlier answer.  You should edit his answer and edit your description into it.

Answer (score 1):

strace is available from Cygwin in the [cygwin package](http://cygwin.com/packages/x86_64/cygwin). You can download it
from a [Cygwin mirror](http://sourceware.org/cygwin/mirrors.lst), for example:

```sh
http://mirrors.sonic.net/cygwin/x86_64/release/cygwin/cygwin-2.0.2-1.tar.xz
#      |                      |                              |     |
#      +-----------+----------+                              +--+--+
#                  |                                            |
#               mirror                                       version
```

strace is one of the few Cygwin programs that does not rely on the Cygwin DLL,
so you should be able to just copy `strace.exe` to where you want and use it.

Comment: It's good, but only seems to work on other cygwin programs. You can't `strace notepad`. It launches notepad, but doesn't capture any system calls.

Comment: @MichaelFox : Yes, it only catch calls to cygwin1.dll.

Answer (score -1):

[strace](https://strace.io/) supported By installation of Windwos [Git](https://git-scm.com/downloads),as Michael Fox Mention Maybe not useful for complex/windows software.

[image]

[image]

Comment: That is the Linux program. It only functions with Linus software/syscalls.

Comment: @HenkPoley not sure what u meant?