# Sniff Inter process communication

Tags: communication, executable, sniffing

I have two applications (.exe) that are running on the same machine (Windows XP x86) and I know are communicating with eachother (I dont know how, I didn't write them). I would like to find a way to sniff the communication between the applications. Is there a way to do this?

I've done some messing with ProMon and i can probably figure it out from there but I'm wondering if there is something a little more specific to this purpose. ProMon can be a bit intimidating.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you could watch your two applications with a system call tracer like [StraceNT](http://www.intellectualheaven.com/default.asp?BH=projects&H=strace.htm) (or [see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3847745/systrace-for-windows)). With some luck, you should be able to figure out whether the processes communicate through a local socket, a TCP connection (via `localhost` undoubtedly), a pipe, a named file, or shared memory.

You can also run `netstat` while the applications are running to see if they are opening any network ports.

Once you know what you're looking for, you can choose a more specific monitoring tool. If it's network communication (even over a loopback interface), you could try capturing the data with something like [WinDump](http://www.winpcap.org/windump/). If the communication is via shared memory, you could attach a debugger to one of the two processes and inspect the shared memory periodically.