# Strace equivalent for windows?

Tags: windows, strace

I am looking for a strace like utility for windows. Are there any(preferably free) alternatives on windows?

Comment: May I have a comment with that downvote? :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3847745/systrace-for-windows

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at Process Monitor from SysInternals.