# Phantom JS takes more than 1 minute to load example.com

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I am new to using `phantomjs`, and I just tried to load and render a page using the example given on the website:

```
var url='http://www.example.com'
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open(url, function() {
  page.render('example.png');
  phantom.exit();
});
```

This takes over one minute to run, as reported by `time`.

I am running on a modern laptop (Thinkpad X1 Carbon) with a Gigabit Ethernet connection, and loading the same page in Firefox takes under a second.

Any hints for finding the root cause of this, or common possible causes of this?

Update: I tried commenting out `page.render` but the running time is very similar, so I do not think it's a rendering speed issue.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to tell where is your bottleneck without any details. Provide a version of phantomjs and platform you're running. Generally, I would try to find where a problem is by perfoming the following steps:

- Try to run phanomjs without js argument, like bin/phantomjs --version

In my case it is 1.9.1. It should respond right away.

- Try to simplify your js, e.g. in your case you can remove:

  page.render('example.png');
- Try to install new version of phantomjs. Or if you have already, try different version.
- Try to look at HAR output:

  bin/phantomjs examples/netsniff.js http://www.example.com

As a result you will see smth like:

```
 "entries": [
            {
                "startedDateTime": "2014-03-07T11:18:49.841Z",
                "time": 1013,
                "request": {
```

So, in my case after phantomjs have been loaded into memory, loading a page took 1013 ms.

If it will about the same for you it will mean, that something going wrong during loading phantomjs itself. You can try to debug phantomjs using *strace*, if you're on Linux or it's [analog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3847745/systrace-for-windows) for Windows.

```
strace bin/phantomjs examples/netsniff.js http://www.example.com
```

Then, see at what system call it stops.