# How do I debug a built-in Python command, package or module?

Tags: python, debugging, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I would like to debug some of the basic packages that come with the Python install and/or are built-in packages, including `pip` and `venv`.

The desire comes from an error message of file permissions (unable to access a file with an "unprintable file name") some of my team is getting running these commands - see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59778734/6501141) for details.

#### Question

How do you debug the Python source code when trying to catch issues in the main python executable, or when directly running a base python module (see following examples for `pip` and `venv`)?

```sh
$ python -m pip install --upgrade
$ python -m venv .venv
```

If it matters, my environment is VSCode, where I am happily able to engage the debugger on any custom script I have written, using the built-in debugger that interacts (I assume) with the main Microsoft Python extension.

Comment: `pip` is a pre-built binary, so if you want to debug that it's most likely going to involve modifying its [source code](https://github.com/pypa/pip) directly and rebuilding the executable. For `venv`, the source appears to be located in the `__init__.py` file under `<python_install>\lib\venv`. In there, you could add `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` to start the Python DeBugger (or just `breakpoint()`, which should work in VSCode).

Comment: @b_c: The `pip` 'executable' is just a Python script that uses the [`pkg_resources` library](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html) to (indirectly) import the `pip._internal.cli.main` module and runs the `main()` function in it. Open the path that `which pip` points to and you'll see it's just text you can add a debug statement to.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Good to know! I didn't see a pip module when I looked (wasn't expecting it to be in `site-packages`) and I didn't consider `python -m pip` would suggest that it _does_ exist as a module somewhere.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Start by looking at the source code for those modules; the `-m` switch looks for a package or module to import first. If it's a package, then Python imports the `__main__` module in that package and runs it as the main script. If it is a module, the module itself is imported and run as `__main__`.

*Usually* the code is structured such that a function is called you can import directly too. You can then just write a bit of code that imports the same function and calls it the same way the `__main__` module would. From there on out it is trivial to run this under a debugger.

E.g. `pip` is a package, so `python -m pip` will import [`pip.__main__`](https://github.com/pypa/pip/blob/master/src/pip/__main__.py) and run that as a script. This then triggers:

```
from pip._internal.cli.main import main as _main  # isort:skip # noqa

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(_main())
```

to be run. You can do the same in VSCode; import `pip._internal.cli.main.main` and call it.

You can *find* the source code for these modules by just importing them and printing out the resulting object:

```sh
python -c "import pip; print(pip)"
```

The representation of a module, if loaded from disk, will include it's filename. If the filename ends in `/__init__.py` it's a package, so you can also double-check that the `__main__.py` file exists:

```sh
python -c "import pip.__main_; print(pip.__main__)"
```

You can do the same for the `venv` module. This one is part of the Python standard library, so the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) actually links directly to the [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/tree/3.8/Lib/venv/), and the [`venv.__main__` module](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Lib/venv/__main__.py) just imports `venv.main()` and calls it.

Comment: Thanks! So find and download the source code - do I also need the "debug binaries" from the main Python installation? I recall checkboxes for those during the original Python installs (on Windows at least).

Comment: @LightCC: `python -c "import pip; print(pip)"` will give you the path to the source code on your harddisk.

Comment: @LightCC: you don't need the Python debug build, no. Nothing here is a binary extension, it's all just Python code.

Answer (score 8):

You will need to set [`"justMyCode": false`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_justmycode) in your `launch.json` for the debugger to trace into third-party code.