# running a cmd command: I want to see (get a protocol) what happens in the background

Tags: windows, debugging, cmd

When I type in a cmd window in my windows OS the following:

```
G:\path\MyWave.wav
```

Then "windows media player" starts and plays MyWave.wav .
But in the cmd window it does not show what processes have run in the background between the command and the play of the file.

What I would like to have, is an output in the cmd window that shows something like this:

```
found G:\path\MyWave.wav
started "C:\Program Files\Windows Media Player\wmplayer.exe"
```

So I want to have something like a protocol, what happens in the background.
Is there any possibility to get this?
For example with a debugging command? Or with a debugging option?

Comment: Nope, no such thing - unless you do it "step-by-step by hand" (like `if exist ".....wav" echo ....` etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [windbg](/questions/tagged/windbg), you can attach to the CMD instance and then do `.childdbg` in order to debug all child processes (such as media player) as well.

A simpler approach is probably to use [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) and see what's going on. If you already know the executables that are involved, you can put a filter for those.

See also: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3847745/systrace-for-windows) which is looking for an equivalent of `strace`.