# When using staticly linked OpenSSL 3.0.8 on some machine legacy provider can't be loaded

Tags: c, windows, openssl

### Background

I have large C++ project which was using OpenSsl 1.1.1t and now I'm tweaking it to use OpenSsl 3.0.8.

To resolve some problem with loading old pfx files I need legacy provider loaded.

### Problem

Following code succeeds on my local machine (Win10):

```cpp
OpenSslProviderHandler::OpenSslProviderHandler(IReporting* reporter, OSSL_LIB_CTX* ctx)
{
    OPENSSL_init_crypto(OPENSSL_INIT_LOAD_CONFIG, nullptr);

    m_defaultProvider = OSSL_PROVIDER_load(ctx, "default");
    if (m_defaultProvider == nullptr)
    {
        reporter->reportCritical(makeSslError(), "Failed to load the default provider");
    }

    m_legacyProvider = OSSL_PROVIDER_load(ctx, "legacy");
    if (m_legacyProvider == nullptr)
    {
        reporter->reportCritical(makeSslError(), "Failed to load the legacy provider");
    }
}
```

Nothing is logged.

On testing machines (Win10, Jenkins), same tests are failing. In logs I can see this critical error report:

```
Failed to load the legacy provider. could not load the shared library (DSO support routines) [asio.ssl:310378599]
```

Then trying to load private key from pfx file fails: "unsupported (digital envelope routines) [asio.ssl:50856204]".

On my local machine I've checked if some new dll-s are loaded by code shown above, but list of loaded dll-s is same before and after this code is executed.

### Tech notes

OpenSsl is build by this script:

```
perl Configure debug-VC-WIN64A no-asm enable-static-engine no-shared no-tests no-nod-module --prefix="%cd%\%INSTALL_PREFIX%" --openssldir="%cd%\x64\Debug" -FS || exit /b 1

perl -i.bak -pe "s/^\s*@\s*$/    @\$(ECHO\)\n/g" makefile || exit /b 1

nmake -k all  || exit /b 1

nmake install_sw install_ssldirs || exit /b 1
```

<del>Here is list of dll-s loaded by my program on my local machine when it works:</del>
Sorry this list was incorrect I've misused "Resource monitor" to get this list of library loaded by a process. When I noticed that I've found `legacy.dll` loaded at `<OpenSsl build prefix>\lib\ossl-modules\legacy.dll`

```
ADVAPI32.dll    10.0.19041.3693 C:\WINDOWS\System32\ADVAPI32.dll
bcrypt.dll  10.0.19041.3636 C:\WINDOWS\System32\bcrypt.dll
combase.dll 10.0.19041.3636 C:\WINDOWS\System32\combase.dll
CRYPT32.dll 10.0.19041.3636 C:\WINDOWS\System32\CRYPT32.dll
CRYPTBASE.DLL   10.0.19041.3636 C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\CRYPTBASE.DLL
dbgeng.dll  10.0.19041.3636 C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\dbgeng.dll
dbghelp.dll 10.0.19041.3636 C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\dbghelp.dll
dbgmodel.dll    10.0.19041.3636 C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\dbgmodel.dll
DPAPI.DLL   10.0.19041.3636 C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\DPAPI.DLL
GDI32.dll   10.0.19041.3636 C:\WINDOWS\System32\GDI32.dll
gdi32full.dll   10.0.19041.3636 C:\WINDOWS\System32\gdi32full.dll
IMM32.DLL   10.0.19041.3636 C:\WINDOWS\System32\IMM32.DLL
KERNEL32.DLL    10.0.19041.3636 C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNEL32.DLL
KERNELBASE.dll  10.0.19041.3636 C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNELBASE.dll
MPR.dll 10.0.19041.3636 C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\MPR.dll
msi.dll 5.0.19041.3636  C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\msi.dll
msvcp_win.dll   10.0.19041.3636 C:\WINDOWS\System32\msvcp_win.dll
msvcrt.dll  7.0.19041.3636  C:\WINDOWS\System32\msvcrt.dll
MSWSOCK.dll 10.0.19041.3636 C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\MSWSOCK.dll
NETAPI32.dll    10.0.19041.3636 C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\NETAPI32.dll
ntdll.dll   10.0.19041.3636 C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
ODBC32.dll  10.0.19041.3636 C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ODBC32.dll
ole32.dll   10.0.19041.3636 C:\WINDOWS\System32\ole32.dll
OLEAUT32.dll    10.0.19041.3636 C:\WINDOWS\System32\OLEAUT32.dll
RPCRT4.dll  10.0.19041.3636 C:\WINDOWS\System32\RPCRT4.dll
sechost.dll 10.0.19041.3636 C:\WINDOWS\System32\sechost.dll
SHELL32.dll 10.0.19041.3636 C:\WINDOWS\System32\SHELL32.dll
SRVCLI.DLL  10.0.19041.3636 C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\SRVCLI.DLL
ucrtbase.dll    10.0.19041.3636 C:\WINDOWS\System32\ucrtbase.dll
USER32.dll  10.0.19041.3636 C:\WINDOWS\System32\USER32.dll
USERENV.dll 10.0.19041.3636 C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\USERENV.dll
VERSION.dll 10.0.19041.3636 C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\VERSION.dll
win32u.dll  10.0.19041.3636 C:\WINDOWS\System32\win32u.dll
WLDAP32.dll 10.0.19041.3636 C:\WINDOWS\System32\WLDAP32.dll
WS2_32.dll  10.0.19041.3636 C:\WINDOWS\System32\WS2_32.dll
XmlLite.dll 10.0.19041.3636 C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\XmlLite.dll
```

### Questions

- What can be source of this error?
- What can be a Win10 difference on my local machine and testing machine (Jenkins), which leads to different behavior (success or failure of loading legacy provider)? Test machine is small virtual Win10 machine with minimum software required.
- is there some actual dll involved? Which one?
- or is there some other root cause why legacy provider doesn't load on other system?

Comment: For using the tag C with the C++ code perhaps.

Comment: @273K I certainly hope no one would do that. [Per the tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c/info): "A question should be tagged with both `c` and `c++` if it is about: ... **C++ code that uses C libraries (for example code using extern "C")**"  Because that would be OpenSSL - which is a **C** library.

Comment: I believe it was misspelled, "C++ code that **uses** C libraries" should be "C++ code that **develops** a C library".

Comment: I'm not a windows person, so I can only make some guesses, based on POSIX. I'd be using `strace` (For windows equiv.: [Systrace for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3847745/5382650)). I'd get a tracking on both systems. To get the legacy provider, it may try to dynamically load it (e.g. `dlopen/dlsym/dlclose`), use it, and then _unload_ it, so it may not show up in your DLL list. Why is openssl _statically_ loaded? Does dynamically loaded help (at least during debug)? Are things installed in the _standard_ places? Are the standard places the same?

Comment: Check legacy.dll has been built as expected and where it has been installed. From your C code you can call `OPENSSL_info(OPENSSL_INFO_MODULES_DIR);` to confirm which directory it thinks it is trying to load legacy.dll from. Check that the modules dir matches the legacy.dll location on your filesystem.

Comment: What is "no-nod-module" in your build script? I do no recognise that as a valid OpenSSL configure option (which is surprising because I would expect the Configure script to complain about this). If this is supposed to actually be "no-module" then the legacy provider becomes "built-in" to the static libs and therefore there is no legacy.dll. I would not expect the legacy provider to fail to load in that case.

Comment: @MattCaswell you are right. This must be some tweak in my corporation fork of OpenSsl. [Here](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/openssl-3.0.8/Configure#L397-L401) I have an extra entry with value `"nod-module"` (and my product do not need this). I do not see this entry in public repo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Root cause

Ok I've found the issue. Problem was shared library which was hiding in place where OpenSsl was build. It was exactly at path `<build prefix>\lib\ossl-modules\legacy.dll`.

On my local machine it was working since test were run at same machine on which product was build.

On Jenkins it was failing, since test were run on test machine (multiple configurations) and my product was copied from building machine (docker) to test machine (virtual machines with required software). Copied content didn't cover OpenSsl build location.

### The fix

Now for a long time I was looking how to make legacy provider part of OpenSsl library and turns out you have to just add one parameter to `Configure` step: `no-module` and whole problem has been solved:

```bash
perl Configure debug-VC-WIN64A no-asm enable-static-engine no-shared no-tests no-nod-module no-module --prefix="%cd%\%INSTALL_PREFIX%" --openssldir="%cd%\x64\Debug" -FS || exit /b 1
```

Disclaimer: `no-nod-module` parameter is just result of some kind OpenSsl fork in my company (detail is not important).

Comment: Your post and answer was very helpful! In case someone ends here with the same issue and still can't solve it - you forgot to define "STATIC_LEGACY".